# Lower bound for complex polynomial on unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(z)=z^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kz^k$. I want to show that if $p(z)\not=z^n$ then $\underset{|z|=1}{max}|p(z)|>1$. Clearly $\underset{|z|=1}{max}|p(z)|\ge1$ but how do I show that the inequality is strict?

Comment: @AhmedHussein Using the estimation lemma we get $1=|a_n|=|\frac{1}{2\Pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{p(w)}{w^{n+1}}dw|\le \frac{1}{2\Pi}\underset{|z|=1}{max}|p(z)|l(\gamma)=\underset{|z|=1}{max}|p(z)|$ where $\gamma(t)=e^{it},t\in[0,2\Pi)$ and $l(\gamma)$ denotes the length of $\gamma$. Is this correct?